# Set boolean with default if options object does not exist

Tags: javascript, boolean, javascript-objects

I want so set a boolean value I either get from a property in an options object, or if this is not defined want to set a default value.

```
const raw = options.rawOutput;
```

If options.rawOutput is not set, the default value should be true.
Problem is: the options object may not exist at all.

Im looking for a more elegant solutions than something like this

```
if (options) {
  if (options.rawOutput) {
    raw = rawOutput;
  }
} else {
   raw = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if `options` exists and if the property `rawOutput` exists, then take that value, otherwise take `true`.

```
raw = options && 'rawOutput' in options ? options.rawOutput : true;
```

or the same but without [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```
raw = !options || !('rawOutput' in options) || options.rawOutput;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to use typeof check:

```
const raw = ((typeof options == 'undefined') || (typeof options.rawOutput == 'undefined'))? true:options.rawOutput;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the power of ES6:

`const { rawOptions: raw  = true } = options || {};`

using object deseructuring to get the rawOptions and assigning it to raw variable and with a default value of true

Answer (score 0):

Try this in case you want to assign false if options is exists but rawOutput is not.

```html
const raw = options ? (options.rawOutput ? rawOutput : false) : true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using just logical operators,

```
const raw = options && options.rawOutput || true;
```

This would set raw to true in case either of options or options.rawOutput is falsy.

Answer (score 0):

When we discuss about `options`, nowadays the approach is having *always* the object defined, to defaults at least. So, for example, in your case, you will have:

```
// list of all defaults value for options
const defaultOptions = {
  rawOutput: true
}


// assuming you are in a function when you get the options
function doSomething(userOptions) {
  // here you will have all the options, with `userOptions`
  // overrides the default options if they're defined.
  const options = {...defaultOptions, ...userOptions};

  if (options.rawOutput) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

This is helpful especially when you have more than one options to pass, and you could have defaults for most of them. In this way, you don't have to check if any object or properties exists every time, and you also have a clear list of the options' default that you can change – or get from a JSON – without impact your code.